# Paste values into new column every nth line

Tags: linux

I have a file.txt like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

if I want to add value (Apple) in a new column with the awk command I can do this:

```
awk -v RS='\r\n' 'BEGIN { OFS = " " } {print $0, "Apple"}' file.txt > file_new.txt
```

which will give:

```
1 Apple
2 Apple
3 Apple
4 Apple
5 Apple
6 Apple
```

Now, let's suppose I would like to have this output instead:

```
1 Apple
2 Apple
3 Orange
4 Orange
5 Banana
6 Banana
```

How to modify the awk command?

Comment: You can use `if else` condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let file be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

You can use:

```
awk  'BEGIN { OFS = " "; a["1"]="Apple";a["2"]="Orange";a["3"]="Banana"; } {print $0,a[int(NR/2 + NR%2)]}' file
```

You will get:

```
1 Apple
2 Apple
3 Orange
4 Orange
5 Banana
6 Banana
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit hackish, but you could read a new fruit from standard input using `getline`, based on the current record number:

```
printf 'Apple\nOrange\nBanana' | 
    awk -v n=2 'NR%n == 1 {getline x < "/dev/stdin" } {print $0, x}' file.txt
1 Apple
2 Apple
3 Orange
4 Orange
5 Banana
6 Banana
```